# Fill Multiple Textbox in a Row using specflow C#

Tags: c#, cucumber, specflow

i am trying to automate a Webpage. in that webpage there is row with multiple columns and some columns have textboxes in it, while doing this i was able to fill value to the first textbox but am not able to fill values for the other textboxes. they have only class name in common.i am doing this using BDD and specflow. Here is the code i am using for filling value into the first textbox:

```
 public void ThenIFilThesheet(TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table table)
    {
        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            var textarea = WebBrowser.Current.TextField(Find.ByClass(row["field"]));
            if (!textarea.Exists)
                Assert.Fail("Class not found ");
            textarea.TypeText(row["value"]);
        }
    }
```

here is the feature file for the same :

```
Then I fil the sheet
| field         | value |
| actuals_hours | 8     |
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be getting the XPath of every textbox which you need to fill in, then locate element by XPath and inserting the value.

Then your table might not look as flashy, but it will work:

```
| xpath                | value |
| //*[@id="wmd-input"] | 8     |
(Just an example of the xpath)
```

And with your code, locate the element by XPath.

This is of course, if I understood your problem correctly. If I did not, and you mean that: only the first field gets filled in while you are expecting all the fields to get filled in, try a "foreach".

Comment: Xpath in the scenario is not a good idea. much better to use the [PageObject pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) and encapsulate that data in the page.

Comment: Bit late to the party, but I agree with the PageObject pattern. If you really want to make it generic, you can make a indexer like `actuals_hours#2`. In your code you'll want to retrieve the collection of objects with class `actual_hours` and set the third one.